# Windows Server 2019 Docker docker.exe: Error response from daemon: failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite):

Tags: windows, docker

I created Windows Server 2019 VM in VMWare and I am trying to run there docker container (Ubuntu) but I get this error

> docker.exe: Error response from daemon: failed to start service
>   utility VM (createreadwrite)

What I already did:

1. I installed Hyper-V and also I enabled Containers in Windows
   features.
2. Enable Nested Virtualization if you’re running Docker Containers
   using Linux Virtual Machine running on Hyper-V `Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true` (machine exists, it's a Linux VM)
3. Enable LinuxKit system `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine")`
4. Restart Docker

Output from docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        2ee0c57608
 Built:             11/13/2019 08:00:16
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

I already followed those threads ([Linux Docker EE Containers on Windows Server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317141/linux-docker-ee-containers-on-windows-server-2016/57691939#57691939),[Cannot start Hyper-V container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404713/cannot-start-hyper-v-container)) but it doesn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found the main issue. VMWare Workstation does not support nested virtualization for AMD Ryzen. When I installed Docker on my Win10 everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

> VMWare Workstation does not support nested virtualization for AMD Ryzen

Actually.... **Billy Smolen** ([`github.com/wbsmolen`](https://github.com/wbsmolen)) from Microsoft mentions in [`MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation` issue 1276](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/1276#issuecomment-640260279):

> So great news -- [win10 build 19640](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/06/03/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-19640/) (in insider's fast ring) has hyper-v support for nested virtualization on amd systems.
>   You must create a hyper-v v9.3 vm. Does not work on kvm hosts.
>
> I got a win10 nested vm to work on a hyper-v host running a 3900x with out-of-box hyper-v settings.
>   Host is already torn down tho in favor of kvm. waiting on kvm to support this.

Comment: This is not yet confirmed for Windows server 2019, but it is a good sign.